# ODE? PDE? Please name the beast

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have the following system:
$$v(t) = \ln(f'(t)) -\ln(v'(t)) +\beta u(t)$$
$$u(t) = v(j)$$
$$j = f(t) -\frac{f'(t)}{v'(t)}$$
Here, $f$ and $f'$ are known functions. Since the system depends on two variables, $t$ and $j$, I understand that it is not a system of ODE's (?). What is it then? and, can it be solved (with an initial condition, e.g. $v(0) = 0$) using canned software?
I can obtain a numerical solution through the iteration
$$v_{n+1}(t) = \ln(f'(t)) -\ln\left(v'_{n+1}(t)\right) +\beta v_{n}\left( f(t) -\frac{f'(t)}{v'_{n+1}(t)}\right)$$
where for every $n$ an ODE solver is called. Would like to know if there is a direct, one shot algorithm.

Any help would be appreciated.

regards

Facundo

Comment: It is neither. ODE and PDE combine values and derivatives at one point in the space of independent variables. I'm uncertain if you could even usefully classify this as a variable delay-differential equation.